# Installing ruby1.8 failed (unable to access dpkg)

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I was trying to install ruby on my remote server(this is a vm machine(debian) in a esxi server . ) I got this error:

The Command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8
```

Error :

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

then I tried :

```
sudo dpkg -- configure -a
```

Output:

```
dpkg: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
```

**UPDATE:**

output of `mount`

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /home type ext4 (rw)

mount: warning: /etc/mtab is not writable (e.g. read-only filesystem).
       It's possible that information reported by mount(8) is not
       up to date. For actual information about system mount points
       check the /proc/mounts file.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: try `dpkg --configure -a` (no space between -- and configure).

Comment: output : `dpkg: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system`

Comment: this is a vm machine(debian) in a esxi server .